# Change global variable in a method

Tags: c#

I have the following code:

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public static int lb1;

    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int lb1 = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

My problem is that I want to change the  `lb1` variable when I click `button1` but everytime I run the program, its running "0", not "1".

What is wrong with what I'm doing?

Comment: You're not assigning to the global, you're recreating the variable.

Comment: You've two different variables.

Comment: Oh really, so What should I do actually?

Comment: Remove the `int` keyword inside the mothod, and move the `public static int` into the class.

Comment: Your code will not even compile because you cannot declare a field outside of a class.

Comment: Thank you for response. I get it.

Comment: @Kovboy Instead of commenting on everything with *Thank you for response*, you up vote if the answer is useful and/or mark the answer as accepted.

Comment: @Jim I can't upvote because of I'm a new in here. So that's why I commented every post "Thank you". What's wrong with this ?

Comment: @Kovboy no worries, there is nothing initially wrong with this. Comments just should be constructive. Imagine every OP will do this on every answer in every question. Welcome on SO btw !

Answer (score 4):

This:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int lb1 = 1;
}
```

Is not the same variable as this:

```
public static int lb1;
```

In the first case you instantiate a **NEW** local variable, (although it has the same name) and it exists only inside the context of the method!

If you want to access the `static` variable inside the method just use the name of it:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lb1 = 1;
}
```

Don't write `int` in front of it, because by doing so you make a brand new variable. Changing it will not affect the `static` class variable.

I almost oversaw the biggest mistake, you have to declare the variable inside the class:

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public static int lb1;

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lb1 = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're declaring a new local variable in the button1_Click method.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lb1 = 1;
    }
```

is what you're after.

Answer (score 0):

You should put your variable inside your class

you can't create global variables like in c++

And you should remove `int` before `lb1 = 1;`

Like this

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public static int lb1;

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lb1 = 1;
        }
    }
```